# How to handle reloading of Iframe in Puppeteer and electron

Tags: iframe, electron, puppeteer

I am trying to automate the process using Puppeteer and electron but I get an error that Iframe is detached and the program stopped.  I will explain the issue in steps so it's more clear.

1. goto site
2. The iframe is loaded with a search box.
3. I fill out the search and press enter.
4. When I press enter the same Iframe is reloaded and now has a search box plus user details.

When I perform step 4 iframe is detached and Puppeteer loses control. At the moment I am using setTimeout to wait for the iframe to reload before I perform any action.

It works but I am looking for a better approach. I have tried many solutions available but none of them seems to work. it got stuck here. `await frame.click(this.GIVEN_CREDIT_SELECTOR);`

```
   ` const page = this.page;
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    const frame = page.frames().find((frame) => frame.name() === 'menu');
    await frame.waitForSelector(this.TEXT_SEARCH_SELECTOR, {visible: true});
    await frame.click(this.TEXT_SEARCH_SELECTOR, {clickCount: 3});
    await page.keyboard.press('Backspace');
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    await frame.type(this.TEXT_SEARCH_SELECTOR, `username\n`);


    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    await frame.waitForSelector(this.GIVEN_CREDIT_SELECTOR, {visible: true});
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    await frame.click(this.GIVEN_CREDIT_SELECTOR);`
```

If I remove await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)); this will stopped working.

"electron": "^27.0.2",
"puppeteer-core": "^21.4.1",
"puppeteer-in-electron": "^3.0.5",

Thank you for help.

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1361#issuecomment-343748051

Comment: Please share a complete, runnable [mcve] of your page and code. Thanks.